# Java initialize the class

Tags: java, class, syntax

```
class Room {
    private String description;  
    private HashMap<String,Room> dir=new HashMap<String,Room>();

    Room(String de){
         description=de;
     }

    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }

    public void add(String s,Room r) {
        dir.put(s, r);
    }
}


class Game {
    Room lobby;   //Syntax error on token";",,expected
    lobby=new Room("pub");
}
```

There are two classes.And the Game class have a problem that says Syntax error on token";",,expected.i am confused.

Comment: just change it to `Room lobby=new Room("pub");`- or move this snippet into a method. What you write is invalid in the class body.

Comment: `lobby=new Room("pub");` that can't be on class level, either use direct initialization: `Room lobby=new Room("pub");` or an initializer-block: `{ lobby=new Room("pub"); }`

Answer (score 1):

Java allows initialization only during

1. Declaration of the variable or
2. Inside a method/block or
3. Inside a block.

JVM allows allocation memory only during the above steps. In the example you have provided, `lobby=new Room("pub");` since its in Class level JVM doesn't know how to allocate memory resulting an error.

Answer (score 1):

Following Java's [Initializing Fields doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), there are three options:

1- Initialize on declaration:

```
Room lobby=new Room("pub");
```

2- Static Initializer blocks:

```
static {
    lobby=new Room("pub");
}
```

3- Initializer blocks:

```
{
    lobby=new Room("pub");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
Room lobby;   //Syntax error on token";",,expected
lobby=new Room("pub");
```

Use inline declaration and instantiation:

```
Room lobby = new Room("pub");
```

You can only have a statement inside a block of code {} (methods, static/instance blocks, other constructs that use a block) in a class.